# How to get date with specific time in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, datetime

I am trying to fetch 1st and last date and time of current month and I have to convert to ISOString.
I tried below but when I am converting ISO its reducing 1 day and after removing it coming proper date .

I have to get 1st and last day of month with time ..

This is what I want to have:

- start datetime `2022-12-01T00:00:00.000Z`
- end datetime `2022-12-31T23:59:59.000Z`

Here is my code:

```js
var date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
        
console.log(firstDay.toISOString())
console.log(lastDay.toISOString())

console.log(firstDay)
console.log(lastDay)
```

Result:

```
// ISO string:
2022-11-30T18:30:00.000Z
2022-12-30T18:30:00.000Z
// without ISO string:
VM4876:4 Thu Dec 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
VM4876:5 Sat Dec 31 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: The issue is the conversion from local (in the *Date* constructor) to UTC (in *toISOString*). "2022-11-30T18:30:00.000Z" and "Thu Dec 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530" represent exactly the same instant in time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Date.UTC()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) to help you construct a date instance at the specified UTC datetime:

```
var firstDay = new Date(Date.UTC(y, m, 1));
var lastDay = new Date(Date.UTC(y, m + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59, 0));
```

Your date instances will now log the expected UTC time:

```
console.log(firstDay.toISOString())
console.log(lastDay.toISOString())

2022-12-01T00:00:00.000Z
2022-12-31T23:59:59.000Z
```

Comment: @RobG thanks, updated to use more precise language

Answer (score 0):

```
let currentDate = new Date();
let cDay = currentDate.getDate();
let cMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
let cYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
console.log("<b>" + cDay + "/" + cMonth + "/" + cYear + "</b>");
```

thats how you get date and time in js

i got it from here : https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-javascript.html

you might want to go over on how to do it.

Comment: This answer seems to miss the OP's issue, which is about the offset shift between UTC and local timestamps.